# Issue with Heroku, configuration variables and django using S3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm having a very strange issue.

I have my django project running in Heroku using S3 to store my static assets.

I wanted to use the Heroku enviroment variables by setting them as follows:

```
heroku config:add AWS_S3_TOKEN=my_s3_token
heroku config:add AWS_S3_SECRET=my_s3_secret
```

And using them with python's os module:

```
import os

token = os.getenv('AWS_S3_TOKEN')
secret = os.getenv('AWS_S3_SECRET')
```

But heroku keeps throwing me the following error:

```
NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

So, I ended up writing those parameters in my settings.py file and it works fine

Why is this happening?

If I run

```
heroku config
```

I can see all my seted variables and if i do

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

and then

```
import os
print os.getenv('AWS_S3_TOKEN')
```

For example, it prints the variable's value.

any clue on this???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app's environment variables aren't usually available while Heroku is compiling the slug and setting up the application, they're only available once the app is running. For a Django app, Heroku will run `collectstatic` as part of slug compilation, which is probably why you're seeing this error.

You can make the environment variables available during compilation by enabling a Heroku Labs feature:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

There's more information in this Heroku dev centre article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with python or Django, but I'm curious.

If you try your authentication with blank strings, do you get the same error?

If so, then I suspect it's about *when* you're doing this authentication dance.  When are you doing it?  At compile time, or at runtime?  (If at compile time, look at [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile))